# Easiest way to read multiple lines (as a sliding window) from a file

Tags: regex, perl

What's the easiest way, in perl, to read a file say, 4 lines at a time?

if a file contains random words like

```
bye
how
are
you
car
bed
dog
```

I'd like to read the file with a sliding window of size 4, so I'd like to read into a string

```
bye how are you
how are you car
are you car bed
you car bed dog
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another example. Each line is pushed onto array `@window`, and if this results in the array holding four elements then the array is printed and `shift` is used to remove the oldest element from the beginning.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @window;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  push @window, $_;
  if (@window == 4) {
    print "@window\n";
    shift @window;
  }
}

__DATA__
bye
how
are
you
car
bed
dog
```

**output**

```
bye how are you
how are you car
are you car bed
you car bed dog
```

Comment: Yes, nice logic.  Instead of bothering to do another `> 4` test, it's easier to just do a blind `shift` at the end of the `if`.  +1 anyway

Comment: @Miller: I agree. I've changed it

Answer (score 2):

Create a buffer, then do line by line processing;

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @buffer = map {scalar <DATA>} (1..3);

while (<DATA>) {
    push @buffer, $_;

    # Show Buffer on a single line
    print join(' ', map {chomp; $_} @buffer), "\n";

    shift @buffer;
}

__DATA__
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
Line5
Lien6
Line7
Line8
Line9
```

Outputs:

```
Line1 Line2 Line3 Line4
Line2 Line3 Line4 Line5
Line3 Line4 Line5 Lien6
Line4 Line5 Lien6 Line7
Line5 Lien6 Line7 Line8
Lien6 Line7 Line8 Line9
```

**Update**

To proactively remove line endings, just do the following.  Output would be identical to the above:

```
my @buffer = map {$_ = <DATA>; chomp; $_} (1..3);

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    push @buffer, $_;

    # Show Buffer
    print "@buffer\n";

    shift @buffer;
}
```

Comment: ideally i'd want to store them in in a string like "Line1 Line2 Line3 Line4. Is there a simpler way to do that? what exactly does map and chomp do?

i will be parsing a very large file so performance is key

Comment: `map` and `chomp` are just removing the line endings from the buffer, so I can print them out.  It would be easy enough to include the `chomp` as part of default processing, but you didn't specify what format you'd want the lines in.

Comment: instead of storing it in an array and then joining to make string, how to store it in a string? i am very new to perl, i just discovered use strict and use warnings which greatly helped my code

Comment: No, the whole point is it's a buffer.  So you have to be able to easily remove the leading element off the buffer before adding one to the end.  If you want to treat them as a string during your processing, you step simply `join` them like I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

Load the words into an array, then you can cycle the array with `push` and `shift`, and print an array slice:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

chomp(my @words = <DATA>);

for (1 .. 4) {
    print "@words[0..3]\n";
    push @words, shift @words;
}


__DATA__
bye
how
are
you
car
bed
dog
```

**Output:**

```
how are you car
are you car bed
you car bed dog
car bed dog bye
```

Comment: what if i wanted to store in in a string with the following format "word1 word2 word3 word4"

Comment: this also seems to be hardcoded for the file. what if i wanted my file contained n words on n lines?

Comment: 1) `"@words[0..3]\n"` *is* a string. 2) You can change the numbers for variables. Not quite sure what you are talking about. This is sample code, you can change it for your own needs.

Comment: You have a slight bug in your code: it's treating the first line of the input as if it were the last.  Also, slurping the whole input into an array is not the most efficient way to do this, if the input can be large.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Thanks, didn't notice. Its just that I print before I reorder the array. Yes, the large input information was added long after I wrote this answer.